# What protein(s) bind together the calcium carbonate tiles in abalone shell to give it strength?

Tags: proteins, marine-biology, structural-biology

The articles that I've been able to find on the structure of abalone shells mention that they consist of calcium carbonate plates connected by proteins, but don't name the proteins. These proteins are key to the shell's strength. What proteins connect the calcium carbonate plates to give the shell its strength? What other proteins are they related to (if any), both structurally and phylogenetically?

I searched via DuckDuckGo using phrases such as "abalone shell protein", "abalone shell structure protein" and "abalone shell structure calcium carbonate protein". The best match I found on proteins was "[In-depth proteomic analyses of Haliotis laevigata (greenlip abalone) nacre and prismatic organic shell matrix](https://proteomesci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12953-018-0139-3)"; while it names many proteins, it doesn't identify their function.

Comment: What did you find when you googled “what is the protein found in abalone shell?” Using this phrase got me a very interesting article.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I used DuckDuckGo. Updated question includes search terms. Looking over "Proteomic analysis of the organic matrix of the abalone Haliotis asinina calcified shell" now.

Comment: The article is quite interesting, but seems focused on identifying proteins for their shell growth function rather than tile binding (the proteins may have both functions). This is ambiguous in parts, since "bind" is also used for CO₃ crystal growth.

Comment: Pif-80 might be one protein identified as potentially binding plates in that it hypothetically "binds in vitro to calcium carbonate crystals" (rather than binding CO₃ molecules together), according to another study (Suzuki et. al., "An acidic matrix protein, Pif, is a key macromolecule for nacre formation", 2009). The proteomic analysis article also describes some proteins as fibroin-like, which could be involved in the shell strength.

Comment: The article also mentions even other species in the same genus have vastly different proteins in their shells, which means the question might be too broad at the given taxonomic rank.

Comment: In that paper alone, you have 14 proteins listed. They were identified by tandem MS (fractionated proteins isolated from crushed shell). Does that paper answer your question in part? I also recommend looking at [a more recent one](https://proteomesci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12953-018-0139-3) where some of the same authors more recently (in 2018 as opposed to 2010) identified 297 proteins from the nacreous shell layer and 350 proteins from the prismatic shell layer, in a different abalone species. A total of 448 proteins were found. Would that satisfy your question?

Comment: @SPr: Unfortunately, no. I'm not only interested in the proteins in general, but the proteins with specific function (as described in the question). The more recent one you mention is also the paper I linked in my question. Neither of the two papers identify with certainty the proteins that connect the CO₃ plates for strength.

Comment: I see. It is difficult to identify proteins with specific niche functionality ("carbonate plate-connecting") by MS/MS. That method is designed to identify isolated proteins, and in this case, the entire shell was isolated. I hope you will find your answer, but it's possible it doesn't exist. Seemingly, the group interested in this research did a whole shell extraction in 2018, and I can't find anything relevant since. I think the protein motifs and domains discussed in the two papers we link here may provide hints. Plate connecting protein(s) must have domains that can interact with carbonate.

Comment: @SPr: Pif-80 and the fibroin-like HasCL10contig2 & P0025F23_658 (mentioned in "[Proteomic Analysis ...](https://proteomesci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1477-5956-8-54)") are the best candidates at this point.